# how can i upload my paperclip image on my own server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

```
has_attached_file :image,
                :styles => { :medium => "300x300", :thumb => "100x100"},
                :default_url => '/assets/missing.png',
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => {
                  :bucket => '#####',
                  :access_key_id => '#####',
                  :secret_access_key => '#####'
                }
```

Here i used AWS to store my images. but i want to store that images on my personal server.

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) for paperclip gem? What is your question?

Comment: @Зелёный  yes i read it but i didn't found what i actually want ?

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#storage

Comment: @Зелёный yes i read above link but  i don't want to use any other server to upload my images. i have my own server and when i upload image in my application it will go to my own server.

Comment: Is this the same server that the app is running on?

Comment: @DickieBoy No, i want to do same as in AWS we store our images on AWS server.i want my server on the place of AWS server.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/xing/paperclip-storage-ftp

Comment: @DickieBoy I integrated it properly and done with store image on my server i can see this image with use of that path in browser. but i can not see that image with same path in my project image/show path

Comment: When you do `@instance.image.url` what is the output?

Comment: @DickieBoy  when i do instance.image.url i am getting path like this => ftp://user/abcd.com/abcd.com/www.abcd.com/photos/241/original/1f609.png  . I can see image in browser with this link but can not see in instance.image.url with the same path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94208/discussion-between-mokariya-and-dickieboy).